# Creating a pivot table based on categorical variables

Tags: r, pivot-table, categorical-data

I am currently doing some analysis in R and can't seem to find a working solution to the following problem:

My raw data is a table containing 3 columns: "user id", "year" and "block". 
The block column can either have a value 'north', 'east', 'south', 'west' or 'other'.

[image: Raw data]

What i want to creat now is some sort of pivot table (not sure if this is the right term to use here). This table should consist of a single row for each combination of user_id and year followed by 5 new columns containing a dummy variable referencing whether or not the customer was sitting in the respective block that year or not. Similar to the example below:

[image: How the result should look like]

I have been trying to get things working through the use of the reshape package in R but it seems to struggle handling the categorical variable "block". 
Any tips/help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Can you provide a reproducible example for us to copy/paste? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should post your data in a numeric way. When you read your data into R just use dput(df) so that we can see the structure like this:  df = structure(list(Userid = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), year = c(2015L, 2016L, 
2015L, 2015L), block = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("east", 
"north", "south", "west"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Userid", 
"year", "block"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` you can try this:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
types <- c("east", "north", "south", "west")
dt[, lapply(types, function(x) sum(block==x)), keyby =.(Userid, year)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method using Base R and `aggregate`:

```
d <- data.frame("User id"=c(1,1,2,3,1), year=c(2015,2016,2015,2015,2015),
  block=c("north","south","east","west","south"), check.names = F)

f <- function(l, vec) {
  vec[l] <- 1
  vec
}

vec <- setNames(rep(0, 4), levels(d$block))
> aggregate(block~`User id` + year, d, f, vec)

  User id year block.east block.north block.south block.west
1       1 2015          0           1           1          0
2       2 2015          1           0           0          0
3       3 2015          0           0           0          1
4       1 2016          0           0           1          0
```

I added an additional data point to show that it can ouptut multiple dummy flags for the same combination of id and year.